# t-SQL Combine multiple rows to one row using key field

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, rows

I have 2 temporary tables

```
#data:
Key     UserID      Driver     Defect1     Defect2     Defect3    Defect4
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
124      151        Paul       Wheels      Windows      Null       Null
124      151        Paul       Null        Null         Null       Null

#data2:
Key     Defect5     Defect6    Defect7
--------------------------------------
124     Seats       Doors     Hood
```

I am looking for a way to combine these 3 rows into a single row based on the Key field, so just rolling them up, ignoring the nulls and moving everything to a single row.  I have pivotted the original data to get it to this point, and am looking for the next step to finish it off please.

I am hoping to get to:

```
#data2:
Key  UserID  Driver Defect1 Defect2 Defect3  Defect4 Defect5  Defect6  Defect7
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
124  151     Paul   Wheels  Windows Null     Null    Seats    Doors    Hood
```

Can anyone suggest a way please?

My defects are incremental based upon a count of the rows (before the pivot) using:

```
SELECT @pivot_list = COALESCE(@pivot_list + ', ', '') + '[' + PIVOT_CODE + ']' 
,@select_list = COALESCE(@select_list + ', ', '') + 
        'LEFT([' + PIVOT_CODE + '], CHARINDEX(''|'', ' + PIVOT_CODE + ')-1) AS [Defect_Item_' + SUBSTRING(PIVOT_CODE, 2, 4) + '] 
        '
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT PIVOT_CODE
   FROM (
      SELECT 'r' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY formresultkey ORDER BY Defect_Item, Defect_description) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS PIVOT_CODE
      FROM #Data3
   ) AS rows
) AS PIVOT_CODES
```

Comment: JOINING the tables with your Key column and then doing GROUP BY Key.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  a.Key,
  a.UserID,
  MAX(a.Driver),
  MAX(a.Defect1),
  MAX(a.Defect2),
  MAX(a.Defect3),
  MAX(a.Defect4),
  MAX(b.Defect5),
  MAX(b.Defect6),
  MAX(b.Defect7)
FROM
  #data a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  #data2 b ON a.Key = b.Key
GROUP BY
  a.Key, a.UserID
```

Comment: Thankyou this works really well. I have added the code to the bottom of my question for how I get the column names for the defects. Your code is exactly what I was looking for but is unable to reference the incremental columns "invalid column name", any further suggestion please? I have ran the code on the other columns and is perfect, just this last hurdle. Thankyou.

Comment: if the columns are not static, then you will need to create a dynamic sql.